# How to limit a Bitbucket Cloud App Password scope to a specific repository

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

Can you limit the scope of an App Password in Bitbucket Cloud to a specific repository?

I know you can make a Repository Access Token, but that isn't tied to my user, and is targetted at CI/CD Pipelines.

Context: I am a consultant working on a client's provided laptop, and want to use my user for regular development (for the usual git logs and PRs and such), but I don't want to give access to the rest of my repositories, only the one for the client.